# my query not null select even with null in mysql database what is the correct syntax here?

Tags: mysql, database

Why doesn't my Sql-statement select only not null values? I only want to select the not null values from `empsched`

[My data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvrsL.png)

This is my query:

```
SELECT
    empID,
    FirstName,
    MiddleName, 
    LastName, 
    Gender, 
    Address, 
    Zipcode, 
    Position, 
    Rate, 
    DateHired, 
    TelNo, 
    empSched, 
    Pstatus, 
    image, 
    Red 
FROM employee 
WHERE empSched IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: If column contains display the 'NULL' then only it checks for NULL. ow if its blank with no default value that means it`s not null.

Comment: Please share your code as plain text, whenever possible.

Comment: other tries plain text @vahdet 
SELECT * FROM `employee` WHERE empSched IS NOT NULL

Comment: I don't see any `null`s in your screenshot, only empty strings. If you want to exclude empty strings as well as `null` values, try `WHERE IFNULL(empsched, '') <> ''`.

Comment: Please put the code **in the question as text**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your empSched column is not null it gives you all the rows.
you can try like this:

```
SELECT empID, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Gender, Address, Zipcode, 
       Position, Rate, DateHired, TelNo, empSched, Pstatus, image, Red 
FROM   employee 
WHERE  empSched IS NOT NULL 
and    empSched <> ''
```

Comment: thanks sir and to all of helping me out there thank you so much